# Hide Edit View link in Newsletter

Tags: views, emails

I have created a view and sending the view as newsletter to users. But received mail contains **EDIT VIEW** link. How to remove the edit view link from newsletter. I have added the screenshot of received email. I am using Mime Mail for sending email.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove permission for anonymous users to edit views from yoursitesname.com/admin/people/permissions

It kind of a long page, so try "ctrl+f" and there type "administer Views" and uncheck the right permission.

If it's not helping, try using another Newsletter module (It's maybe a bug since there is no logical reason to give to email subscribers edit your views, of course).

Please update in comment what worked for you.

Comment: I have unchecked the permission but not working

Comment: Try to flush all caches (also called clear all caches) from admin > performance. you could also do it faster with the module Admin menu or from Drush. If it won't work then so just replace a module).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution

In views, Under Advanced tab, Select yes option in **Hide contextual links**. I have added the screenshot[image]